# grails unable to work on windows with NTLM proxy

Tags: grails, grails3

am trying to setup grails 3.3.0.RC1. When i execute grails from command line its shows the following error

```
Resolving dependencies...
Error |
Error occurred running Grails CLI: connect timed out (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

after some search , i realized that the problem might be proxies . for that i have NTLM http proxy.

How do i configure that ? I want to set the properties for proxy like for always i dont want to run grails like this

```
grails -Dhttp.proxyHost=www.somehost.org -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttp.proxyUser=userid -Dhttp.proxyPassword=password -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost
```

even with the above configuration it is still error.

STACKTRACE:

```
grails --stacktrace
Resolving dependencies...
| Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: connect timed out (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:414)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:643)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DecompressingHttpClient.execute(DecompressingHttpClient.java:137)
        at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.execute(HttpTransporter.java:287)
        at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.implGet(HttpTransporter.java:243)
        at org.eclipse.aether.spi.connector.transport.AbstractTransporter.get(AbstractTransporter.java:59)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:447)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:350)
        at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:581)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:249)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:520)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:217)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:535)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:519)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:409)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:363)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:351)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:254)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:341)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.grape.AetherGrapeEngine.resolve(AetherGrapeEngine.java:319)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.grape.AetherGrapeEngine.resolve(AetherGrapeEngine.java:301)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.grape.AetherGrapeEngine.resolve(AetherGrapeEngine.java:293)
        at org.grails.cli.boot.GrailsDependencyVersions.<init>(GrailsDependencyVersions.groovy:53)
        at org.grails.cli.boot.GrailsDependencyVersions.<init>(GrailsDependencyVersions.groovy:49)
        at org.grails.cli.profile.repository.MavenProfileRepository.<init>(MavenProfileRepository.groovy:53)
        at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.createMavenProfileRepository(GrailsCli.groovy:334)
        at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.execute(GrailsCli.groovy:235)
        at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.main(GrailsCli.groovy:159)
| Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: connect timed out
```

i have added GRAILS_OPTS in environemt **-Dhttp.proxyHost=www.somehost.org -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttp.proxyUser=userid -Dhttp.proxyPassword=password -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost** but no luck . what the heck is this ?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of places you may need to set properties.  I think what you really need is to prefix your properties with "grails." wherever you're setting them now.  Grails forks a process now and only passes system properties that are prefixed (you can change this if you want, but it's not recommended).

```
-Dgrails.http.proxyHost=whatever
```

However, you may also want to set properties in your gradle.properties file.  Don't leave any blank; just don't put the line if they should be blank.  You can add username and password here too.  For these, they don't need a prefix.

```
systemProp.https.proxyHost=your proxy
systemProp.https.proxyPort=80
systemProp.http.proxyHost=your proxy
systemProp.http.proxyPort=80
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts:whatever
```

Comment: ma men . i dont have a gradle installed but i use wrapper for my android projects if you have worked with android studio.

Comment: I don't have gradle installed either (actually I may?  I don't remember for sure but I'm not using it directly), but grails 3 uses a gradle wrapper by default, which uses gradle.properties.

Comment: i have that folder in setting but still no luck

Comment: Did you prefix your existing -D settings with grails. also?

Comment: yes sir. let me update you +1 for your continues effort